# Keep sort in Many to many relation in JPA

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, orm

Say you have an Indicator object available in a predefined list of countries selected by user when creating the indicator. The list of countries is sorted in a specific way (not alphabetically or any trivial way) by the user and he wants to have them sorted in all the app.

```
@Entity
public class Indicator {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Country> countries;

    //Getters, setters
}

@Entity
public class Country {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    //Getters, setters and other attributes
}
```

Is there a simple way in JPA to keep the order of countries list ? I tried using @OrderColumn with a sort_order in the join table but it didn't come as expected.

Do I have to map the join table, thus losing direct access to countries from indicator ?

Comment: You'll need to describe what exactly you've done with @OrderColumn, as that is what you should be using. This will force JPA to maintain the order in the DB, so that what you have in your entity when writing it out is the order it will give back when reading it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@OrderBy("name")
@ManyToMany
private List<Country> countries;
```

Comment: Does not work if user did not sort them alphabetically. The only solution I see right now is to add a "sort_order" field in the join table

Comment: You can add sortOrder attribute to Country and @OrderBy("sortOrder") to the countries field